# How to use Unicode Fonts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, unicode

I would like to know how to use Unicode fonts in Word-press. I mean that I need to use Sinhalese fonts in the site. So how can i do that?

Thank you
Asanka

Answer (score 1):

download google input tools for sinhala ( or what ever language you need ) from here http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/ and install. You'll have to select language from the language toolbar at the task bar - right corner to type in sinhala.

Type what ever you need in sinhala in the wordpress post edit screen and publish. You'll see it in sinhala.